# Sdk for fingerprint Egistec es603 Needed

Tags: fingerprint, biometrics

I am using this device
http://www.egistec.com/en/sensors/fingerprint-es603wb.aspx

and i wish to develop a attendance application using .net, but the 
problem is i don't find any SDKs in the manufacturers website , please help with the sdk or suggest what to do now

Comment: Hi @naveen-margan , you posted this issue a long time ago, but I'm curious if you were successful using this driver with Microsoft framework. Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fingerprint Sensor you are using supports a Microsoft Developed Windows Biometric Framework that can enable you to use this device to create Client Applications to save and process data feed from the device.

You can read more about the framework at the following links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463081.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463089.aspx

The API for the framework that you can use in your .NET Attendance Application is here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd401509(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I followed your link, while trying the code mentioned in this page ,
it says **To compile this sample, link to the Winbio.lib static library and include the following header files:**

How do i link that ?

Comment: Hi Naveen, You will find Winbio.dll in your OS itself. The most probable path to this dll is 1. %windir%\system32\winbio.dll
%windir%\winsxs\backup\x86_microsoft-windows-s..y-biometrics-client_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7000.0_none_2282a6cbc0bff05e_winbio.dll_7228629e
%windir%\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-s..y-biometrics-client_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7000.0_none_2282a6cbc0bff05e\winbio.dll

Answer (score 1):

There is a WBF (Windows Biometric Framework) driver for ES603 from 6/2/2015. You can download the correct driver from the provided link below.
http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=egistec
I tested the driver and it works well with WBF.
There are some minor problems with the provided EGISFP.inf file and driver. The driver is not signed and you should disable the driver signing for your operating system also you should remove some lines from EGISFP.inf file provided with the driver. I do not know the purpose of these lines but without removing them it was not possible to install the driver.
You can edit the EGISFP.inf file provided with the driver with a notepad or some other text editor.

Removed lines from EGISFP.inf:

```
[TargetComputers]
{1ed80287-8fee-5541-86c7-02746d111ec6}
{1acaf813-928c-5ce1-9012-8f3a7b526d89}
{254096e0-4db0-5e60-99ab-12a4f047c0ec}
{9fb1291b-c8a4-54b6-97fc-b7ece2b7db41}
```

Answer (score 0):

No that device is not supported by WBF. I have tried it already, no go.